# Ransack - Unknown action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, ransack

I'm new to RoR and I want to use Ransack on my project.

map_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @q = Tweet.order('id_tweet DESC').search(params[:q])
  @tweets = @q.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page]).per(5)
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :text_cont, :value => 'Filter...' %>
  <%= f.submit "Src",:class => "btnSrc"%>
<% end %>
```

However, it does not work. Searching for "foo", I get this link:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/tweets?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Btext_cont%5D=foo&commit=Src
```

And this:

Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/tweets"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

What's happening? Anyone can help?

Comment: At first sight, this has nothing to do with Ransack, but rather with your routes. Looks like your routes file has no entry for your tweets controller... It also surprises me that you have called your controller map_controller, and not tweets_controller?

Comment: Thanks. I had to redirect from /tweets to index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Route problem, as imagined.

```
match '/tweets' => 'map#index'
```

This solved the problem.